# Can't get the link to vertical align

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a language bar dropper, that will show links to alternative versions of my site. So far, I have:

```
<div id="lang_dropper_wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.chambresdhotesdev.org/new_design/blank.gif" class="sprite-luna">
    <b class="down_arrow" style="float: right;">&nbsp;</b>
    <div id="lang_dropper">
        <a class="smaller lang-en" href="#">English</a>
        <a class="smaller lang-fr" href="#"> French</a>
        <a class="smaller lang-es" href="#">Cases rurals</a>
        <a class="smaller lang-mobile" href="#">Mobile</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and then the CSS:

```
.lang-en:before, .lang-es:before, .lang-fr:before,.lang-mobile:before {
    content: ' ';
    /*background: url(/new_design/sprites-all-2.png) no-repeat;*/
    width: 32px;
    height: 26px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.lang-en:before {
    background: green
}

.lang-es:before{
    background: red;
}

.lang-fr:before{
    background: yellow
}

.lang-mobile:before{
    background: maroon;  
}

#lang_dropper a:link {
    display:block;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: middle;
}
#lang_dropper a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #eee;
}
#lang_dropper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10000000;
    /*display: none;*/
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    width: 200px;
}
#lang_dropper_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 2px;

}
#lang_dropper_wrapper:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am actually using a CSS sprite for the flag icons - thus the confusing stuff in there with the :before stuff, and a class for each one.

My only remaining issue - is getting the bleedin thing to vertically align!

You can see a working example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjQgRe

It works perfectly, apart from the fact I want the text to be vertically aligned with the flag colored icons to the left of them

I've tried all kinds of things, but just can't get it to work.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align:middle` for your inline block elements.

```
.lang-en:before, .lang-es:before, .lang-fr:before,.lang-mobile:before {
content: ' ';
width: 32px;
height: 26px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
vertical-align:middle; /* Add this style */
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/chekh4hd/)

Comment: OMG - you legend! I can't believe I didn't try that. I've literally been looking over the code for the last hour, trying all sorts of things! I'll accept this as the answer, as soon it will let me :)

Answer (score 0):

Its taken display block by default.so actually if you not given even it is fine.

```
li a 
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<style>
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<div id="lang_dropper_wrapper">
<img src="http://www.chambresdhotesdev.org/new_design/blank.gif" class="sprite-luna">
<b class="down_arrow" style="float: right;">&nbsp;</b>
<div id="lang_dropper">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="smaller lang-en" href="#">English</a></li>
    <li><a class="smaller lang-fr" href="#"> French</a></li>
    <li><a class="smaller lang-es" href="#">Cases rurals</a></li>
    <li><a class="smaller lang-mobile" href="#">Mobile</a></li>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually moved away from using `ul li` elements, as I couldn't get that to align correctly either (with the pseudo sprite image)